# Azure Data Factory Error 'item' is not a recognized function PT2

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have asked a similar question, however this question relates to a SINK location.

I have configured my sink as described
[image]

My configuration looks like the following:
[image]

Can someone let me know what I need to do get resolve this error?
Let me know if you need more details

I have passed the @item as a Parameter, see image.
Any suggestions as to what to now Place in the Directory
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: From which activity are you getting the @item.Currency value? Are you using `for each` activity in the pipeline?

Comment: "item" is an iterative property of a pipeline loop and is not available in a Dataset. You'll need to pass the value to the Dataset as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the following dynamic content as a value in the **Directory** field of `File Path`. The below would fetch the required output.

```
@{dataset().Directory}
```

- But the warning `'item' is not a recognized function`  would impact the dataset only if `@{item().Currency}` is absent. If this dataset is used appropriately in a pipeline, it would fetch the required results anyway.
- `@{item().Currency}` is valid inside `for each` activity. Since you are using `@{item().Currency}` in the dataset that is being used inside `For each Currency` activity (as sink of copy activity and hence *@item().Currency is valid*), it would give desired results. Look at the following demonstration.
- I am using `@{item().Currency}` in the dataset called `op1`.

[image]

- I am using the above `op1` dataset as my sink for copy data activity (which is inside for each activity).

[image]

- Now when I click **Debug**, though there is a warning saying  `item' is not a recognized function`, the pipeline would succeed without any errors (I used lookup activity for demo).

[image]

- The copy activity runs successfully and writes the required file into a folder structure of the given format. The following is an image of my blob storage (my sink).

[image]

- So, you can ignore the warning message as long as you are using `@item().Currency` with a dataset that is present inside a `For each` activity where `@item().currency` is a valid value.

**NOTE:** You cannot use the above dataset for other activities of pipelines where `@item().Currency` does not exist. If you do so, the warning message prevails, and the pipeline would fail with an error.

Using `@{item().Currency}` inside the dataset directly is not incorrect as you can see from the above demonstration. But it is a better practice to pass the value to a `dataset parameter`.